# Вывести кликабельный телефон в правильном формате

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<a href="tel: <? include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/iphone.php");?>"><? include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/iphone.php"); ?></a>
```

Выводит телефон в таком виде

```
<a href="tel:8 (922) 22-22-222">8 (922) 22-22-222</a>
```

А надо, чтобы выводилось

```
<a href="tel:89222222222">8 (922) 22-22-222</a>
```

Содержание файла iphone.php текстовое, там нет никакого кода, просто телефон:

```
8 (922) 22-22-222
```

То есть нужен вывод только цифры без пробелов.
Помогите, уже голову сломал))

Вот нашел более короткое решение

`<a href="tel:<? echo(preg_replace("/[^\d]+/s", "", file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/iphone.php")));?>"><? readfile($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/iphone.php"); ?></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться пользовательским потоковым фильтром:

```
class digitsonly_filter extends php_user_filter {
  function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
  {
    while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
      $bucket->data = preg_replace('#\D+#', '', $bucket->data); // Удаляем все не цифры
      $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
      stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
    }
    return PSFS_PASS_ON;
  }
}
stream_filter_register("str.digitsonly", "digitsonly_filter")
    or die("Failed to register filter");
```

Теперь:

```
<? $iphonePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/iphone.php"?>
<a href="tel:<? include("php://filter/read=str.digitsonly/resource=$iphonePath")?>"><? include($iphonePath); ?></a>
```

[Демонстрация работы фильтра](https://3v4l.org/hgkTa)

Comment: Как разместить потоковый фильтр?

Comment: Где угодно в php коде до момента использования.

Comment: Ничего не понял, но работает!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="call()"><? include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/iphone.php"); ?></a>

<script>
function call()
    let phone = '<? include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/iphone.php'); ?>';
    phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
    window.open('tel:' + phone);
</script>
```

Comment: Не работает предложенный вариант